# ASP.NET AJAX Website not working on InternetExplorer ( but on other browsers is doing ok)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer

I have asp.net web site which uses AJAX ( including AjaxControlToolbox), 
I have button which populates PlaceHolder which some data from database.
PlaceHolder is placed in the UpdatePanel and some UpdateProgress "loading image" is connected to it.

Everything is going fine on Chrome, Opera or Firefox, but on IE(7 & 8) when I click the button, the "loading image" appears, as the data are beeing taken from database (the amount of time is similiar to the same process on other browsers, so I presume this is going ok), but at the end, PlaceHolder is not populated with anything. No Error is displayed, just nothing happenes... I guess data is read from database but after that, there must by some problem.

Please help. I really need it to work on IE.

Comment: *Snarky comment about my hate for all things IE* Seeing code to look at would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It still feels like an error is occuring in the AJAX javascript being run on the page in IE.  Have you checked that the option to display "all errors on the page" is enabled in IE so it's not hiding anything from you.   Also use Fiddler (or the like) to make sure that the AJAX request is being made and a response is coming back.

In the worst case, put some alert(...) messages in your code to see if that highlights the point at which the code stops working / processing to give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I had AnimationExtender added to the UpdatePanel, and the IE could not handle one of the animations there. I figured out which animation it was and deleted it.

Thanks for all the help.